# Splunk: Unable to get the correct min and max values

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm a newbie as far as Splunk is concerned with modest regex skills.

We have events with the following patterns:

```
fallbackAPIStatus={api1=133:..., api2=472:...,api3=498:...}
fallbackAPIStatus={api1=3535:...}
fallbackAPIStatus={api2=252:...,api3=655:...}
```

The numeric value indicates the response times and the ellipsis inidcates fields that I'm not interested in.

The number of apis within the braces is dynamic (between 1 and 4)

I want to be able to create a table as follows:

```
apiName   TotalRequests  Max-Response-Time  Min-Response-Time 
api1           2            3535           133
api2           2             472           252
api2           2             655           498
```

Here's my search:

```
index=my_logs  sourcetype=my_sourcetype | rex field=_raw "fallbackAPIStatus=\{(?P<fallBackApis>[^\}]+)\}" | eval temp=split(fallBackApis,",") | rex field=temp "(?P<apiName>[a-zA-Z-]+)=(?P<responseTime>[0-9]+):"|stats count as TotalRequests  max(responseTime) as Max-Response-Time min(responseTime) as Min-Response-Time by apiName
```

I'm able to get the TotalRequests right but I'm not able to get the correct max and min response times

Can someone advise what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an issue with your field extraction, the following works fine

```
| eval temp=split(fallBackApis,",") | rex field=temp "(?<apiName>\S+)=(?<responseTime>\d+):"
```